# How to pixel-perfect align text to the top of the div?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am trying to adjust a text to align to the top of a div exactly, so that the top of the highest characters are 'touching' the top of the div. I need a scalable solution regardless of specific sizes, and it can include CSS and JS manipulation/calculations. I know of table, table-cells and vertical-aligns, but these still do not shift the text exactly to the top.

Here is an example: https://codepen.io/saar62097/pen/MMLmyr

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
}

#text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 60px
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="text">hello world<br>how r u?</div>
</div>
```

I would like the text to "touch" the top of the div.
Any ideas? thnx!

Comment: it's already touching the top. add `ÂÄÊ` and see

Comment: Some familiarity with the semantics of [typography](https://material.io/design/typography/understanding-typography.html#) might help identify the various 'gotcha' scenarios you'll run into here.

Answer (score 0):

I've added a **`line-height`** and changed it until it matched to the '**touching**' div margin. Since **`top: 0;`** isn't working for text.

```css
#container{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 0;
}

#text{
  top: 0;
  color: white;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 43px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="text">hello world<br>how r u?</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If we change font-size, we also have to change line-height, there is no universal way to do it. I don't think it's that hard to change both values.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a typography unit to position it. For example, I used negative margins in `em` to test with different font sizes.

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
}

#text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-top: -0.25em; /* Negative margins in typography Unit */
}

#container2 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-left: 350px;
}

#text2 {
  font-size: 30px; /* Half the font-size */
  color: white;
  margin-top: -0.25em;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="text">hello world<br>how r u?</div>
</div>

<div id="container2">
  <div id="text2">hello world<br>how r u?</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that this is **usually** *highly* typeface dependent. What works for one font will not necessarily work for another. It entirely depends on the glyphs and box size.

Comment: @Paulie_D Do you see any Cross-typeface solution for this? Are there any CSS hacks like https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-4/#font-size-adjust-prop when combining with the hack. I see CSS has developed very far since last time that I am out of options to look for an article.

Comment: No...typefaces are *highly* different from one another. The glyph boxes are often all different sizes. The space is there *for a reason* (to make multiline text readable) and we should not encourage (ideally) this being overridden. That's not to say that there may not be *specific* typefaces with no vertical spacing but I don't know of any examples.